# How can i add the gender column?

Tags: python, string, numpy, using

I have this dataset with 5 columns and lots of rows. I've been asked to get the total number of male and females. They are string and can't figure it out. I have to use numpy too.
Please help.
Thanks[image: The dataset]

```
ls = gender.values.tolist()
ls
top = []
for i in ls:
    if i == 'M':
        top.append(i)
        print(i)

I need to sum of the male and female in the above dataset.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value_counts` from pandas to see total number of occurrences of a categorical column.

In your case, it can be

```py
df['gender'].value_counts()
```

IT will return the count of male and female.

Comment: This is Pandas. Yes I've done this. I want to use numpy to do it. Thank you